# Selector being performed when trying to set UITextField text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, recursion, uitextfield

i'm trying to clear a UITextField whenever the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event is being performed.

However, when I set the text to nothing, the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event is being called again, and this is the way it keeps going.

This is my code:

```
- (void)updateText {
    //other code
    textfield.text = @"";
    //other code
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(updateText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}
```

I would like to be able to set the text of the text field without it looping infinitely!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way, but before you do your programmatic update to the textfield you could remove your UIControlEventEditingChanged listener and then add it again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

do

```
- (void)updateText {
    //other code
    if (![textfield.text isEqualToString:@""]){
       textfield.text = @"";
    }
    //other code
}
```

it is probably not the most elegant solution but it is very quick and will surely work

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to deregistering for the event, and reregistering is to put in a BOOL to guard against this particular recursion.

```
@interface MyClass : () {
    BOOL clearText;
}
```

and in the method:

```
- (void)updateText {
    if (clearText){
        clearText = NO;
        return;
    }
    //other code
    clearText = YES;
    textfield.text = @"";
    //other code
}
```